# Regular expression - 1st random character equal to the 2nd one.

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to have a regular expression in PHP like `"/A.B./i"` but the random character following A and the random character following B should be equal.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$regex = '/A(.)B\1/i';
```

The `\1` referencing the captured group `(.)` is called a [back-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) (as @Ilmari Karonen was kind enough to remind).